# Over writing server port of the application.yml in the command line

Tags: spring-boot

I want to overwrite sometimes the server port while launching my application

By default I use this command :

```
nohup java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar myJar.jar &
```

The server port is configured in the application.yml with this line :

```
server.port: 8990
```

And sometimes I want to use this one :

```
nohup java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar myJar.jar -server.port=8081
```

But the server port is not overwritten. How should I do that?

Comment: Should be `-Dserver.port=8081` since you'd be [defining a system property](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html), not passing parameters to Maven itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--` to override your properties

```
 java -jar myJar.jar --server.port=8990 --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-arguments)

Another option is [`ApplicationArguments`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-arguments) in order to have access to various arguments.

> The ApplicationArguments interface provides access to both the raw `String[]` arguments as well as parsed `option` and `non-option` arguments

Comment: I've read this doc but I didn't find this explanation about how to overwrite Yml in command line, thanks Anton

Comment: Yo can do it the same way. For example. If yaml file has  `retry: 3` you are overriding it using the following `--retry=5`.